# Condensing a block of code that includes converting from string to float and then calculating the mean and std to be more efficient in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wrote the following code to find the mean and standard deviation of a 1D array, but I feel that it could be condensed and achieve the same results in fewer lines.

```py
genericInfoIndices = [i for i, s in enumerate(messageType) if "GENERIC_INFO" in s] #find the indices of messageType array and assign the variable            
genericInfoSize = np.array(messageSize)[genericInfoIndices] #find the values of the indices of messageSize array that correspond to the variable set above     
genericInfoSize_float = genericInfoSize.astype(float) #convert the values from string to float            
genericInfo_mean = np.mean(genericInfoSize_float) #find the mean using numpy             
genericInfo_std = np.std(genericInfoSize_float) #find the standard deviation using numpy
print(genericInfo_mean, genericInfo_std) #print mean and standard deviation values
```

The first line of code goes into the messageType array and extracts the indices that contain the string "GENERIC_INFO". Once I get that list of indices I look for the values in the messageSize array that correspond to the indices I found in the first array. Then I convert those strings into float. Then do the mean and std calculations with numpy. I'm trying to figure out if I can combine the second and third lines of code in the block above.

I ran the block of code and the results were what I was looking for but I am looking to condense the code a little bit.

Comment: In second line when writing np.array define dtype=float and remove second line,

Comment: Since it is clear you can't combine the `np.mean` and `np.std` lines, or remove the last print, you could condense the question to focus on the 2nd and 3rd lines.  Strip of the comments, and what's left isn't much :)  Condensing the `astype` step isn't much of a simplification, especially since you don't tell us much about the `messageSize`.  If it is already float dtype you don't need any further casting.